# Creating value indicator measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a Column A in a table that has valid values and blank values. I want to create a value indicator measure in power BI. I am not sure how to do it as I am new to Power BI.

in sql, we usually do,

case when column A <> '' then Y

else N

So, how do we implement this in measure in power BI? Could you please help me out? I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a **calculated column** with

Indicator = IF( ‘Table‘[Column A] <> ‘‘, “Y“, “N“ )